# JsGrid issues, data loads from the db but doesn't save changes for edit/delete

Tags: jsgrid

I have been using JSGrid for a express CRUD application. The data from MongoDB/Mongoose fetches the data in fine, but when I update/delete on the jsGrid, it works but then on re-load doesn't save. Basically doesn't save into the MongoDB. I've tried a few things and looked through similar posts, but can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong? 
JSGrid Code in Javascript

```
$(function() {
var filter =
 $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
  height: "450px",
  width: "900px",
  filtering: true,
  inserting: true,
  editing: true,
  sorting: true,
  paging: true,
  autoload: true,
  pageSize: 10,
  pageButtonCount: 5,
  deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete client?",
  controller: {
      loadData: function(filter) {
          return $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "/projects",
              data: filter
            });
        },
      insertProject: function(filter) {
            return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/projects",
                data: Project
            });
        },
      updateproject: function(Project) {
          return $.ajax({
              type: "PUT",
              url: "/projects",
              data: Project
          });
      },
      deleteproject: function(Project) {
          return $.ajax({
              type: "DELETE",
              url: "/projects",
              data: Project
          });
      }
  },
  fields: [
      { name: "title", type: "text", width: 150 },
      { name: "location", type: "text", width: 50 },
      { name: "resources", type: "text", width: 200 },
      { type: "control" }
  ]
```

}); 
});

Answer (score 1):

Your controller has implemented the wrong methods.  The correct method names are as follows:

```
...
controller: {
    loadData: function(filter) {}, 
    insertItem: function(item) {}, 
    updateItem: function(item) {}, 
    deleteItem: function(item) {}
}
```

...